# WAPT response time

Tags: load-testing, response-time, wapt

I’m a beginner of WAPT and I run the test with 100 fixed user and I want to know the avg response time with page element. Which one I need to check? 
1. Avg response time under summary or 
2. Avg under response time. 
3. Avg90 under response time
Thanks in advance.